# Data is not getting posted to php file while using cURL

Tags: php, api, post, curl

I'm trying to create a simple API using PHP but the data doesn't get posted to the file.

```
$url = "http://localhost/api.php";
$session = curl_init();
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 200);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data'));
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array("process"=>"login","user"=>$_POST['user'],"pass"=>$_PO    ST['pass'])));
printArr2($session);
$result = curl_exec($session);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($session, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($session);
```

**The following is the API**

```
if(isset($_RESPONSE['process']))
{

    if(!strcmp($_RESPONSE['content']['process'],"login"))
    {
        $con = dbConnect();
        $str = userLogin($con,$_POST['content']['user'],$_POST['content']['pass']);
        if(is_bool($str))
        {
            $jsonData = json_encode($str);
            header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            header("Content-type: application/json");
            echo $jsonData;
        }
        else
        {
            $jsonData = json_encode($str);
            header("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorised access");
            header("Content-type: application/json");
            header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
            echo $jsonData;
        }
        dbClose($con);
        exit;
    }

    if(!strcmp($_POST['process'],"plagiarism"))
    {
        $con = dbConnect();
        $user = $_POST['user'];
        $text = $_POST['text'];

    }
}
else
{
    $jsonData = json_encode(array("Error"=>"No methods called"));
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
    {
        header('HTTP\1.1 400', true, 400);
        header("Content-type: application/json");
        header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        echo $jsonData;
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Invalid entry";
    }
}
```

Whatever I do the output is always the "else" part of `isset($_RESPONSE['process'])`.

I tried putting "process" as get by appending it to the URL.

```
$url = "http://localhost/checkapi.php?process=login";
```

Comment: It's not posted to what file? You're not saving it to any file.

Comment: I've pasted the api. check it out

Comment: I think you have mixed up $_REQUEST with $_RESPONSE. But, as daniel axel writes below, use $_POST instead.

Comment: {"Host":"localhost","Accept":"*\/*","Referer":"http:\/\/localhost\/checkapi.php","Content-Type":"plain\/text","Content-Length":"43"}

Comment: Thank you guys that worked. There's one more thing I'd like your help with.

Comment: How to set header response code? I've tried several combinations in php but none of them gets reflected at the client side.

Comment: header('HTTP\1.1 200', true, 200);

Comment: header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");

Comment: http_response_code(200);
http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an invalid array index (['content']) in your $_RESPONSE and $_POST super globals.

```
if(!strcmp($_RESPONSE['content']['process'],"login"))
    {
        $con = dbConnect();
        $str = userLogin($con,$_POST['content']['user'],$_POST['content']['pass']);
```

Instead you need:

```
if(!strcmp($_POST['process'],"login"))
    {
        $con = dbConnect();
        $str = userLogin($con,$_POST['user'],$_POST['pass']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a post request, the best way to access those variables is:

```
vardump($_POST);
```

Try printing that in your API before the if so you can debug.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but typo: it should be "var_dump": 
var_dump($_POST);